# UDP sockets and MSG_PEEK

Tags: linux, sockets

When we use `recvfrom()` to read a packet from UDP socket, we cannot read it partially. Because if we read a small part of UDP packet first(by passing a small buffer), the reminder of packet is dropped as mentioned here:

> All receive operations return only one packet.  When the packet is
> smaller than the passed buffer, only that much data is returned; when
> it is bigger, the packet is **truncated** and the **MSG_TRUNC** flag is set.

But I wonder if the same thing happens if we just inspect packet using `MSG_PEEK` flag. Will reminder of packet is dropped if I just peek the UDP message?

Comment: Why don't you write some simple test code to check the behaviour and then come back to report it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will reminder of packet is dropped if I just peek the UDP message?

Nothing will be dropped, since with the `MSG_PEEK` flag set, the state of the socket's incoming-data-buffer is not modified; the entire packet will remain in the socket's buffer.

Only the first part of the packet's data will be copied into your too-small destination-data-buffer, of course.